# What may be an inefficient estimator of the population mean?

Tags: estimators, efficiency

If the sample mean is an efficient estimator of the population mean, what may be an example of an inefficient such estimator?

Comment: It is not that simple. For example sample mean is an efficient estimator for population mean for data coming from Gaussian, but not from Laplace distribution. Similarly sample median will be efficient to estimate population mean for Laplace but will be inefficient to estimate population mean for Gaussian.

Comment: Well, ok, but I mean the "vanilla case", so I guess Gaussian. Would the median of the sample be an example of an inefficient estimator in this case?

Comment: Pick one element of the sample randomly as your estimator.

Comment: I don´t understand.

Comment: OK, let's be more explicit.  Your setting is a sample of values $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n.$  Roll an n-sided die.  Call its outcome $i.$  Let $x_i$ estimate the mean.  I hope it's obvious that for $n\gt 1$ this is an inefficient procedure.

Comment: Nope. It´s all jibberish to me.

Comment: What @whuber is telling you is not using your entire data also leads to an inefficient estimator. Estimator is a function of your data such as $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. This function doesn't have to be in the form of adding elements or doing symmetric/commutative operations. It can be anything. And if this function doesn't use some of its input arguments that will (always, I think) lead to inefficiency.

Comment: Lars, since my comments aren't making sense to you, we had better back up a bit: could you explain what you understand an "estimator" to be and what your definition of "efficiency" is?

Comment: Ok, estimator = a entity used for estimation of another entity. Efficiency = Measures with more accuracy/validity-ish?

Comment: Those might be good heuristics but they're ultimately worthless for reasoning through questions like yours.  You need to refer to some clear, quantitative definitions.  In so doing, I think my comments might become more understandable, because they assume a conventional understanding of these terms as expressed in statistical literature and textbooks. Here's a search that might take you to some useful posts on our site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=efficient+estimator+score%3A1

Comment: Is there anyway of explaining this (e.g. why median is efficient for Laplace and mean is efficient for Gaussian) in a way that a layman or schoolkid could understand?

Answer (score 6):

Consider a sample of size $N$ drawn from a normal distribution. The sample median $\tilde{X}$ is an unbiased and consistent estimator for $\mu$. For large 
$N$ the sample median is approximately normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance 
$\pi/2N$. The efficiency for large $N$ is thus $2/\pi \approx 0.64$. This is the asymptotic efficiency, that is the efficiency in the limit as sample size $N$ tends to infinity.

**Edit:** The sample mean is a better (more efficient) estimator for the population mean as opposed to the sample median, because the sample median will miss the population mean by more (on average) than the sample mean.

That is, the sample medians (talking asymptotically - as the sample size N reaches infinity) will have a wider distribution compared to the sample means. And since both estimators are unbiased, meaning they will estimate the true population mean - meaning they wont under/overestimate the population mean, all that remains is to look at the variance of these estimators. And as written above, the sample median distribution will have a higher variance compared to the sample mean, which means the sample median is a less efficient estimator for the population mean.

Comment: That doesn´t answer my question. I was asking for an example of an INEFFICIENT estimator.

Comment: @LarsAhnland In this case the median is inefficient because the efficiency is roughly 0.64. The efficiency of the mean is 1.

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry, I don´t understand much of that. But in short: I the normal case, the sample mean is more efficient than the sample median for estimating the population mean?

Comment: @LarsAhnland Yes.

Comment: Thanks! And this is because - normally - the median produces more variance?

Comment: @LarsAhnland Yes, in this case the sample median is more variable.

Comment: Wait... the median produces more variance when it is more variable? That is just circular logic. Can it be explained in a simple/layman way?

Comment: @Lars user2974951 was not "using circular logic". When they said "the sample mean is more variable" they were just reframing the statement of your question to a more correct usage of the terminology than what you had in your question. Their response was simply "Yes." and then simply a clarification of what they were saying *yes* to. If you have looked up the definition of [efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics)#Estimators) of estimators, then it should be clear that a comparison of variances (given both estimators are unbiased here) is simply following ... ctd

Comment: ctd... the definition of efficiency - to be precise, their *relative efficiency* will be the ratio of the reciprocals of their variances, so the more efficient has a smaller variance.the definition of efficiency - to be precise, their *relative efficiency* will be the ratio of the reciprocals of their variances, so the more efficient has a smaller variance.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Is there any inherent logic that makes a median having higher variance than a mean ?

Comment: @LarsAhnland (For a normal distribution) If you want to estimate the population mean then you should use the estimator best suited for the job, the closest thing to it, the sample mean. The median also works but is not as efficient. You would use a hammer to hammer a nail, you could use a shovel but it wouldn't be as easy - it would take longer on average compared to a hammer. I can't make it any simpler than this.

Comment: I understand this, but why is the variance higher for the sample median?